# reCATPCHA redirect isHuman=false

Tags: python, google-app-engine, recaptcha

Hi I [added reCAPTCHA](http://www.koolbusiness.com/ai) to a page so far that it can verify a client. Now I want a more graceful failure when `isHuman = False`with a redirect to the form page in such case with a message on the form page that reCAPTCHA failed. Can you inform what to do rather than just outputting "captcha failed?" so that it can redirect to the form page with Google App Engine's request handler? Here's my code:

```
def post(self, view): #edit
    challenge = self.request.get('recaptcha_challenge_field')
    response  = self.request.get('recaptcha_response_field')
    remoteip  = os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    cResponse = captcha.submit(
                 challenge,
                 response,
                 CAPTCHA_PRV_KEY,
                 remoteip)

    if cResponse.is_valid==True:
        isHuman=True
    else:
        isHuman=False 
        self.response.out.write('captcha failed')
        return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for a way to redirect back to your original posting page you can use:

```
self.redirect('your_url')
```

You could also include a GET variable in the url so that the page is aware that the CAPTCHA failed.

Comment: That's very good. But how to make it more like form values are kept between requests?

Comment: @Web Are you using a forms library like Django forms?